# How to add a second button to the react form that not execute the first button handler function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an React form.
This form have a button.
This is the submit button.
If i click this button execute the first function (submitHandler)which pointer is on the form.

I want add a second button to the form the "back button".
This button should execute an other function but not the first function

Both button should be on the same form

Form.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Form.css";

const Form = (props) => {
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Some console log now from Submit Hanlder')
  };

  const secondFunction = event =>{
  
    console.log('Some other console log')
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <div className="new-expense__controls">
        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>Amount</label>
          <input type="number" />
        </div>
        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="date" />
        </div>
        <div className="new-expense__actions">
          <button type="submit">Submitting</button>
          <buton>Second button....</buton>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: Button defaults to type `submit`. Have the second button `type="button"`, e.g. `<button type="button">Second button....</button>`, to avoid executing the submit handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `type="button"`:

```
<button type="button">Second button....</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a onClick event to the second button to execute the secondFunction:

```
<button onClick={() => secondFunction()}>Second button....</button>
```

**Note:** the onClick event in reactjs is with a Capital letter C.

```
const secondFunction = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Some other console log')
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you'd have to `preventDefault`, `onClick{(e) => { e.preventDefault(); ...` in this case since the default behavior is to submit the form. Using `type="button"` would avoid this scenario.

Comment: Yes I think this is correct i updated the answer.